# Integral Area Question Concerning 3 Functions

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble trying to teach someone how to do this problem.  I've tried at least 6 times, and it must be something I'm missing.  The question "Find the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded on the left by the $y$-axis, below by $y=x/3$, above left by $y=x+4$, and above right by $y=-x^2+10$."  I've tried almost everything I can remember.  I don't know what to do with the right curve of the parabola between the two functions.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Splitting it up into two separate areas.  Switched functions for f(x) and g(x).  Tried getting the whole parabola area then subtracting.

Answer (score 1):

The following graphic might help. What you need to find is the limits. In this case, you will need two integrals. For example, the red and green curves intersect at $x=2$, so the first integral will simply be

$$\int_0^2\int_{x/3}^{x+4}dydx=\int_0^2(x+4-x/3)dx$$

Ignore the double integral if that doesn't make sense. You can think of this as integrating over the entire region with a function of constant value $1$, which is visually a 3d object with the base in the plane and depth $1$. OR you can think of integrating along a line with a function whose value is the area between the two curves. This probably makes mores sense to a student who has taken one or two calculus courses.

Then you need to do the second integral, which goes from $x=2$ to $x=3$. Note that these values of $x$ are found by finding the intersections of two curves (set them equal and solve for $x$), but in this case you can also eyeball it and test to make sure you get the right answer.

[image: Plots]

Comment: So I don't need to integrate -x^2+10?  My second integral would be ∫23(x^2+10−x/3)dx, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "don't need to integrate" but yes. With a negative before the x^2 by the way. Cheers!

Comment: I still haven't got the correct answer.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can also use wolfram alpha and type thing like "integral of blah blah from 0 to 2"